Can I ask here about ghost?
Sorry I cant chat here yet.
Is this the rite site to ask about ghost.
I see and feel bad ghost. Are they real? How do I deal with that?

thanks. I'm taking zoloft.

You'd be able to ask about ghosts at New Age proposal.

Added proposal tag for 'parapsychology'.

No, unfortunately we won't be able to help you.
The policy of this site is that we cannot accept "self help" questions and if you are seeing "bad ghosts" which are disturbing to you, you should seek help from a medical professional/psychologist/therapist.
I wish you the best of luck!

I think Josh summarises your question well regarding the self-help aspects.
That said a few questions that might be on topic for this site related to ghosts:

Why do people believe in ghosts?
How does belief in ghosts affect X?
How does X influence belief in ghosts?

In general, whether ghosts are real is not on topic on this site. However, the belief itself could be on topic.
